# SQL Update involving two tables with multiple column conditioning

Tags: sql, sql-update, ssms

I have two tables:

[image]

and

[image]

I would like to update Table Second according to the contents of columns A,B and C in Table First. The colours in the diagram are to clarify how the update should occur.

I have obviously simplified the real problem, but I tried this:

```
Update Second
set Group = (select distinct Group
             from First 
             where First.A =Second.A
               and First.B = Second.B
               and First.C = Second.C)
```

but I was getting an error

> Cannot insert the value NULL into column 'Group'

when in fact both tables don't have NULL values. I presume because there are several rows on both tables it is maybe more complicated than I think?

Comment: Tag your question with the database you are using.

Answer (score 1):

In Standard SQL, you can express this basically as (well, `group` is not an allowed name):

```
Update Second
    set Group = (select max(f.Group)
                 from First f
                 where f.A = Second.A and
                       f.B = Second.B and
                       f.C = Second.C
                ) 
    where exists (select 1
                  from First f
                  where f.A = Second.A and
                        f.B = Second.B and
                        f.C = Second.C and
                        f.Group is not null
                 );
```

There may be alternative syntax available in specific databases.

Note the change to the subquery to guarantee that it returns exactly one row.

Comment: perfect! This works a real treat. I think due to the multiple rows that I have of the combinations it was more complicated than necessary. Thank you very much!

Answer (score 0):

You need an extra where at the bottom so it doesn't try to update the wrong rows:

```
where second.a in (select a from first where First.A =Second.A
               and First.B = Second.B
               and First.C = Second.C) 
and second.b in (select b from first where First.A =Second.A
               and First.B = Second.B
               and First.C = Second.C) 
and second.c in (select c from first where First.A =Second.A
               and First.B = Second.B
               and First.C = Second.C)
```

Otherwise, and this is not recommended unless you are sure there is a single group for each row AND no blanks:

```
Update Second
set Group = (select top 1 Group
             from First 
             where First.A =Second.A
               and First.B = Second.B
               and First.C = Second.C 
order by group desc)
```

So yeah, option 1 if it works is best in my opinion, I have done option 2 before in certain scenarios too.

Comment: I used option 2 and I got the same error message. The weird thing, is that the Group is defined in both tables as not null. So I don't understand where a NULL can arise from.

Comment: Sounds like there is still a row in the second or first table that isn't in the other table. As annoying as the first option is to write out it really is the better statement. Try running this to get your problem rows: Select * from second left outer join first on first.a = second.a and first.b = second.b and first.c = second.c where first.a is null or first.b is null or first.c is null

Comment: I believe through the multiple rows that I have I got the following error message when I tried the first option. Error 512: Subquery returned more than 1 value. This is not permitted when the subquery follows =, !=, <, <= , >, >= or when the subquery is used as an expression.

Comment: Sounds like duplicate data then, I would go for a group by within the embedded select first, if that fails you might have to cross your fingers and go for a top 1